# saving instance state on memory low situations

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-dialogfragment, low-memory

i have an alert dialog wrapped around by a `DialogFragment` class. the dialog has custom layout in which i show a list of items (i use a `ListView` with an appropriate adapter). the list of items is pretty huge and important, so i save it inside a `Fragment` class in my `DialogFragment`'s `onPause()`, just like in [this example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject).

everything works perfectly, except one very rare situation: when i leave the app with the dialog window open (by pressing the "home" button) and the device gets low on memory, it kills my app's process. when i come back to my application later, it tries to recreate the dialog, but crashes (i get a `NullPointerException` inside my dialog's `ListView` adapter), because it cannot restore the list of items that was shown in my left open dialog. this happens because the `Fragment` in which i store the dialog's state is also destroyed when system kills my app's process so my `DialogFragment` cannot recreate its dialog as it has no source of data for its list adapter.

what i want from you is to offer me a better way to save the state of my dialog window so it could be recreated even after my app process is killed or to show me a way to cancel the dialog if the list of items is `null` before it gets resumed (i mean to cancel the dialog somewhere during its recreation). i don't consider a database a good way to store that data, as it would take too long. i'd prefer a way to stop the dialog's recreation if there is no information for its adapter.

UPDATE:

implementing `Parcelable` to save your objects during the application's lifecycle is really a splendid idea. writing objects to `Parcel` is fast (trust me, you won't see any delay between lifecycle changes until you start using it inappropriately), and the process of saving and restoring your app's instance state is governed by `ActivityManager` process, so even if not only your `Activity`, but also the process hosting your whole application is destroyed by the Android system, `ActivityManager` maintains the `Parcel` where your objects were saved in and restores their state if `Activity` is being recreated from scratch in a new process. big thanks to @Naveed for encouraging me to try this practice!

NOTE FOR THOSE WHO STILL DOESN'T CATCH WHAT SAVING INSTANCE STATE REALLY IS ABOUT:

saving instance state of your `Activity` along its lifecycle events means maintaining the changes of information that are meaningful only for your application's CURRENT UI or user's CURRENT progress, but are not essential to your application or users when they explicitly stop the app (by pressing the back button) and start it again later. this particular form of information that is really temporary should be saved within the `onSaveInstanceState()` callback method in the `Bundle` object by using the `put...()` methods for primitive Java types or implementing the `Parcelable` interface in your custom classes, and later restored in `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()` callbakcs.

all the other data that is important for the users no matter whether they explicitly close your application or leave it just for a short time should be saved in a persistent storage, such as an `SQLite` database or a `SharedPreferences` system so it may be restored whenever the user or your application needs its previous progress again.
you should save this form of data within `onPause()` callback method, because it is the last method guaranteed to be called before the system is able to destroy your app's process in case it needs to recover some resources. if you choose to save the data in a method called after the `onPause()`, i.e. `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`, you are in a huge risk of not getting the data saved, because those methods might never get called if the system decides to kill your app immediately in some very bad (but not necessarily rare) case.

another thing: please only use `SharedPreferences` when storing small amount of data, as it's not built for storing lists, collections or bundles. Consider spending just a couple of hours more to implement an `SQLite` database interface for your application and use it more comfortably to maintain large chunks of information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system will call `onSaveInstanceState` when it is about to kill your app because of memory problems.  You can save any state related information in [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).  If your data is a primitive type, Parcelable, or Serializable it can be saved in a bundle.

When the Activity is recreated you can restore it in `onRestoreInstanceState` or `onCreate`or any of the following in the [fragment life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html).

```
onCreate(Bundle) called to do initial creation of the fragment.

onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) creates and returns the view  hierarchy associated with the fragment. 

onActivityCreated(Bundle) tells the fragment that its activity has    completed its own Activity.onCreate(). 

onViewStateRestored(Bundle)tells the fragment that all of the saved state of its view hierarchy has been restored.
```

If you simply don't want to show the dialog. Then you can do the null check in `onResume` and don't create the adapter if data is null and dismiss the dialog if it is visible.

Update: example parcelable:

```
public class MyObject implements Parcelable {

        private String myString;
        private int myInt;

    protected MyObject(Parcel in) {
        myString = in.readString();
        myInt = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(myString);
        dest.writeInt(myInt);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyObject> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyObject>() {
        @Override
        public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyObject(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MyObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyObject[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: the list of items for the `ListView` is saved  inside a `List<MyCustomItem>` collection, so the process of writing it to a `Bundle` is really confusing (i would have to override the `List<>` and implement `Parcelable`) so i don't prefere it as a solution. and how not creating an adapter would stop the dialog from showing? it would still be displayed, but empty... i need a way stop the whole dialog from showing if data is `null`.

Comment: And you can dismiss it from onResume() if it is visible. However its not that difficult to implement parcelable.  You only need to implement for your custom object and change the list to arraylist (since array list implements serializable already)

Comment: oh, okay, i see that it is possible to put an `ArrayList` of `Parcelable` objects into a `Bundle`, but, for some reason, i still don't consider making my custom item class a `Parcelable` object a good practice, as the process of serializing my list would be very slow (the items list is pretty huge). and is there a guarantee that that `Bundle` would survive after my app's process got killed?

Comment: That is the reason Parcelable was created, to speed up the `Serialization` process. See [here](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/).  If your list is really huge then maybe you should think about implementing some kind of on demand loading.

Comment: are you sure that if i save my list in the `Bundle` it will survive after my process is killed? because `Fragment` with `setRetainInstance(true)` didn't...

Comment: Yes that is the point of `savedInstanceState` .  Retained fragment only survives long as its parent activity so if the your activity is dead, the system will be free to pick up the retained fragment. It is mostly used to handle rotation and not necessary low memory situations.  `savedInstanceState` on the other hand is written to disk when low on memory and then read back on restoration.

Comment: This is from documentation of onSavedInstanceState() "This method is called before an activity may be killed so that when it comes back some time in the future it can restore its state. For example, if activity B is launched in front of activity A, and at some point activity A is killed to reclaim resources, activity A will have a chance to save the current state of its user interface via this method so that when the user returns to activity A, the state of the user interface can be restored via onCreate(Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)."

Comment: okay, i will try to implement the `Parcelable` and see what will happen. if everything goes right, i'll accept your answer, but you have to show an example of `Parcelable` implementation in your answer, please.

Comment: Try out this website http://www.parcelabler.com/  . It will generate all the parcelable code for you.

Comment: i've just implemented `Parcelable` and it seems to work perfectly. i've know it for a long time, but never thought of it as of some preferred (good) way for saving and restoring instances of some Android objects. big thanks to you for encouraging me to try this practice. again, it works. thank you for your idea!